# Is there any way to change the fonts of salesforce service console details pages?

Tags: service-cloud-console

Is there any standard way to change the font of detail pages in the salesforce service console without embedding detail tag in visualforce page?
I know such configuration for portals but does such configuration is available for service console app. I don't see such settings on salesforce console app settings.